# How to check which ImageButton was prssed?

Tags: android

I have lots of image buttons. User can press any of those button and i need to know which button is pressed. These buttons appears dynamically so i don't know how much of them will be.
For one image button i would write this listener:

```
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TravelBite.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But how to do one listener for all my Images Buttons? Can i recognize which button was pressed by it's tag ? Like tag would be ID from sqlite.

Also i put image to button with this code:

```
button.setImageDrawable( testPic );
```

`button` is ImageButton and `testPict` is drawable (image)

But when i press this button it don't show that it is pressed if i do this:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent_background);
```

I had to do this because i just want to see Buuton image which i could press and recognize what i pressed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) View.setTag(object) and View.getTag() and store in it sqlite id. Something like this:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TravelBite.this, (String)v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //or some function that do somthing useful
                //if( ((String)v.getTag).equals("image1") ){} or anything else
            }
```

And in for loop:

```
String tagFromSqlite = "image1";
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
ImageButton.setTag(tagFromSqlite);
ib.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ok what you can do is that you can write a single callback function and then set it to each and every button it will allow you to handle each button with a sing function like :

    View.OnClickListener btn_listener = View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Do whatever work you want.
                        int id = v.getid();
                        // check for id and do you task.
                    }

Arraylist<Button> btn_group = new Arraylist<Button>;
or
Arraylist<int> btn_id_group = new ArrayList<int>;

    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        btn.setId(i);
        btn_id_group.add(i) or btn_group.add(btn);
        btn.SetOnClickListener(btn_listener);
    }

I think it will work for you.
```

Comment: But how to recognize which button was pressed ? My button should keep some id that i would know what i need to select from sqlite

Answer (score 0):

```
final OnClickLisener listener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v){
         switch((Integer)v.getTag()){ 
         case R.id.zero:
            break;
         case R.id.one:
            break;
         case R.id.two:
            break;
         }
     }
}

//when init the Buttom
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(Context);
btn.setTag(NUMBER);
```

Comment: This won't work i don't get buttons from XML i need to create them dinamically. This int id = v.getId(); in listiner reuturns me -1

Comment: This worked btn.setid(NUMBER); maybe you know if this can be used for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to manually assign ID's to keep them separated - I had to do something similar (1000 was the base ID I chose to add upon as well)

Although View v in the listener refers to the button pressed, when you programmatically create buttons the id's are not unique and caused me issues, so that's why I set them specifically

```
View.OnClickListener btn_listener = View.OnClickListener() 
{
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
            //you can use v.getID() here
      }
}

for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn.setID( 1000 + i );
    btn.SetOnClickListener(btn_listener);
}
```